# How do I add a Delegate for AddressOf CalledBack?

Tags: vb.net, delegates, vb6-migration

Made an attempt or two to add a Delegate ...unsuccesfully.

```
   Public Function CallbackAddress() As Integer
  'UPGRADE_WARNING: Add a delegate for AddressOf CalledBack Click for more: 'ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/dv_commoner/local/redirect.htm?keyword="E9E157F7-EF0C-4016-87B7-7D7FBBC6EE08"'
    CallbackAddress = GetAddress(AddressOf CalledBack)
    End Function

    Private Function GetAddress(ByVal address As Integer) As Integer
        'GetAddress = address
        Return address
    End Function
```

Here is the failed  (incomplete or completely wrong) attempt to add a delegate:

```
  Public Delegate Sub CalledBackDelegate(ByVal param As Integer)

  Public Function CallbackAddress() As Integer
        Dim myCalledBackDelegate As CalledBackDelegate = New CalledBackDelegate(AddressOf CalledBack)
        CallbackAddress = GetAddress(myCalledBackDelegate)  // << This doesn't work! 
    End Function
```

Still ending up with an error:

> myCalledbackDegate Can't be converted to integer.

What am I missing?

Comment: How is the return value from `CallbackAddress` used?  I'm suspicious that this is an XY problem where you really need to just remove `CallbackAddress` entirely and replace it with something else.  It looks like something being used for a low-level hook that might need to be done completely differently in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

All three proposed function, are functions that return an integer.  And while it is of course possible to have a function that returns a delegate, having one that returned a **fixed** delegate would be rather pointless.

A delegate is a reference to a function, and is used to call a function where you don’t know at the call site what method you will be calling.  This is now more commonly done with a lambda function.  Below is a complete application that shows how delegates and lambdas (a particular type of delegate) are commonly used today.  Your example is missing the usage, so we can’t really help you with that.  Hope this helps clarify the concept.  (Excuse the layout, using iPad).

```
imports System

Public Module Module1
  Public Sub Main()

    console.Write("Enter a number:")
    Dim x as integer = if(integer.tryparse(console.ReadLine().trim, x), x, x)
    console.Write("Enter another number:")
    dim y as integer = if(integer.tryparse(console.ReadLine().trim, y), y, y)

    console.Write("Enter a plus or minus sign:")

    dim operation = console.ReadLine().Trim()

    dim op as func(Of integer, integer, integer)

    select case operation
        case "+"
            op = addressof add
        case "-"
            op = addressof minus
    end Select
    Dim result = op(x, y)


    console.WriteLine($"Result of {x} {operation} {y} is {result}")

    dim lambda as func(of integer)

    select case operation
        case "+"
            lambda = function() x + y
        case "-"
            lambda = function() x - y
    end select 

    result =lambda()
    console.writeline($"Result of {x} {operation} {y} is {result}")

  End Sub
  public Function Add(x as integer, y as integer) as integer

    return x + y

  end Function

  public function Minus(x as integer, y as integer) as integer
    return x - y
  end function
End Module
```

Comment: Which "usage" are you reffering to ?

Comment: @JamesT.Smith: primarily where you are trying to assign it and where it is being used.